# Does Outlook, as a Drop Target, support IAsyncOperation?

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop, iasyncoperation

I am playing with [Creating something from nothing, asynchronously [Developer-friendly virtual file implementation for .NET improved!]](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9917797).

This brilliant article demonstrates how to create a customized DataObject implementing delayed data extract on drop/paste and asynchronous data trnasfer on background thread.

It worked perfectly untill I tried to drop a file into Outlook 2016. It still works but the UI is not responsive despite the fact that my dataobject has "IsAsynchronous" set to true.

After debugging I found when dropped to Outlook IAsyncOperation.GetAsyncMode is not called and IDataObject.GetData is called on the UI thread.

My question is does Outlook support IAsyncOperation? If it does what am I missing? If it does not support IAsyncOperation, is there a workaround or different solution?

Regards

Xiao

Comment: Have you checked this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/application-support-bumper and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/start-menu-reg

Comment: @Evanzheng Thanks for the information. Yes, I did read the "Transfer with shell object..." part and it does not tell you what if the drop target does not support IAysncOperation and for the register start menu part I do not understand why it is related unless there is a way to enable async for Outlook from command line.